# Принтер как сериал устройство

Tags: ubuntu, принтер

Стоит задача отправлять на принтер массив байтов.

Собственно сам вопрос как настроить принтер как последовательный порт.

ОС ubuntu 18
принтер custom

Comment: На windows есть готовая программы, для линукса таких я не нашел

Comment: `cat massiv_baytov.txt >/dev/lp0` или на какое там устройство у вас в системе встал принтер.